# Ranorex and remote UI

Tags: ranorex

Reading through the Ranorex documentation, I'm unsure how you can run these tests unattended. When running from a CI process, do you need a separate machine that operates the UI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running unattended coded UI tests, a dedicated computer (VM) is required and must be configured to run UI tests (no screen lock).

It can be either started manually at the end of the day using Ranorex test suite runner (which is acceptable as a first step towards test automation) or automatically using a test controller.
Usually, the test controler is integrated to the build server and executes tests automatically on newly available builds.

The following is an article describing the integration with Jenkins:
http://www.ranorex.com/blog/integrating-ranorex-automation-in-jenkins-continuous-integration-process

If you are more familiar with Microsoft (Team Foundation Server), the following is a good article on how to integrate Ranorex to Microsoft Test Manager (and Team Build):
http://www.ranorex.com/blog/running-ranorex-automated-tests-using-microsoft-test-manager

Finally, there is another good article describing the integration of Ranorex with Jenkins/TestLink:
http://www.ranorex.com/blog/integrating-ranorex-with-testlink-and-jenkins-2

Answer (score 1):

When you're running a Ranorex Runtime on a server you can send the server's (this could be your CI server but I would suggest to have your software running on a test server) current session to the console. ( %windir%\System32\tscon.exe 0 /dest:console ) . This way you won't need a real screen and you can schedule a job in Jenkis as said by SuperHugh.

This way you can use it unattended